# Why is the Jacobian matrix equal to the matrix associated to a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given the linear transformation $f$, we can construct the matrix $A$ as follows: on the $i$-th column we put the vector $f(\mathbf e_i)$ where $E = (\mathbf e_1, \ldots, \mathbf e_n)$ is a basis of $\mathbb R^n$.

Now, I read that for linear transformations, if we use the canonical basis of $\mathbb R^n$, the matrix $A$ is equal to $J f$ (the Jacobian matrix associated to $f$). It's indeed so for the few examples that I tried, but I cannot find a proof of this fact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^p$ is linear, then you know that for all $a\in\mathbb{R}^n,$ you have that $Df(a)=f.$ As $Jf(a)$ is the matrix which represents $f$ in the canonical bases $\mathcal{C}_n$ and $\mathcal{C}_p$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^p,$ you will have that 
$$Jf(a)=[f]_{\mathcal{C}_p\mathcal{C}_n}=A,$$
with your definition of $A.$

Comment: Thanks. I am used to different notation and so I'm having a bit of a hard time completely understanding what you wrote. What do you mean by $Df(a)$ and $[f]_\star$?

Comment: Here $Df(a)$ is the differential of $f$ at the point $a,$ which is often written $df_a$ when we work in finite dimension, and for a linear map $f:E\to F$ (with bases $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{C}$), I note $[f]_{\mathcal{C}\mathcal{B}}$ the matrix which represents $f$ with the process that you precise in your question (when $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ are the canonical bases of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^p$, then vectors and their vectors of coefficients are the same and so here there is no "problem").

Comment: Ahh yes, now I understand, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome !

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly then what you are trying to prove is not true.  The Jacobian of f is the best linear **approximation** to f at a given point.  It is equal only if the function f happens to be linear.  That is exactly the same as saying the derivative of f(x)= ax is the constant, a.

Comment: Well yes, I supposed $f$ to be linear.